# Drawing a plane in ThreeJS with Point and Normal Vector

Tags: three.js, plane

I would like to draw a plane in ThreeJS with a point (e. g. 0, 10, 20) and a normal vector for the plane orientation. I simply just do no get the position or the orientation right. Please help me out. Regards

Here are two ways I've tried (with PlaneHelper):

```
const plane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(10, 10, 10), 3)
// does not work: planeObj.translate(new THREE.Vector3(100, 100, 100))
const helper = new THREE.PlaneHelper(plane, 50, 0x00ffff);
this.scene.add( helper )
```

Or without the PlaneHelper:

```
const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 50, 50, 32 );
geometry.translate(100, 0, 0)
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
const plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( plane );
// normal orientation missing
```

Comment: Tip: The plane normal must have unit length.

Comment: I'm sorry. What do you mean with "unit length"?

Comment: It means the length of the vector is 1. Call `vector.normalize()` to do that. Normals and direction vectors in three.js must be normalized.

Comment: Thank you, the orientation of the plane changes. However, it is moved by the normal vector away fromt he center??

Comment: See https://threejs.org/docs/?q=plan#api/en/math/Plane. If you have trouble understanding these concepts, you might want to consider getting help at https://discourse.threejs.org. I know this topic can be confusing at first.